# Spritekit removeFromParent() on iOS9 issues

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, sknode

My app creates several SKNodes and SKSpriteNodes dynamically based on incoming events. When I try to cleanup obsolete nodes and their contained sub-nodes I use node.removeFromParent().

However as soon as I try to use the cleanup code using deinit's on all node layers I immediately get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The most safe version I think should be the following piece of code and it badly fails with the mentioned exception as well:

```
deinit {
   if self.child1.parent!.children.contains(self.child1) {
       self.child1.removeFromParent()
   }
}
```

So to sum it up: the child node has still a parent (self.child.parent != nil). Even finding child1 in the list of the children of its parent says: hey I'm still there and po child1 and po child1.parent! shows valid node objects. But still removeFromParent() makes the app crash.

Log messages in deinit() show that the deinitializers are only called once per object...

I was able to reproduce it in a small project. The essential things should be contained in those two classes:

```
import SpriteKit

public class ContainerNode : SKNode {

    private let myNode : CustomNode

    override init() {
        self.myNode = CustomNode()
        super.init()
        self.addChild(self.myNode)
    }

        required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        deinit {
            self.myNode.removeFromParent()
            self.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

    public class CustomNode : SKNode {

        private let containerNode : SKNode
        private let child1 : SKNode

        override public init() {

            self.child1 = SKNode()

            self.containerNode = SKNode()

            super.init()

            self.containerNode.addChild(self.child1)

            self.addChild(self.containerNode)
        }

        required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        deinit {

            if self.child1.parent!.children.contains(self.child1) {
                self.child1.removeFromParent()  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here !!
            }

            self.containerNode.removeFromParent()
            self.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var myNodes = [ContainerNode]()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if myNodes.count >= 5 {

            self.removeAllChildren()

            self.myNodes.removeAll()

        }

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let node = ContainerNode()
            node.position = location

            myNodes.append(node)

            self.addChild(node)

        }
    }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true

            let skView = self.view as! SKView

            skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true;
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

The code can be pasted into the standard Spaceship demo (it loads the gamescene file of the demo). Click 6 times on the background. The first 5 clicks add nodes to the scene. On the 6th click all nodes are going to be removed programmatically then which should make the app crash.

Any ideas appreciated. Is this an Apple bug or did I miss something ?

XCode 7 GM, crash in Simulator and on IPhone5...

Comment: Added the controller and the view classes. The game scene file is the out of the box scene file of the Spaceship demo in XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the reason for the crash.

SpriteKit simply is not thread-safe and I was using it in a multi-threaded way (basic rendering loop plus a separate thread receiving network packets which in the same thread updated the scene graph of SpriteKit too). The unpredictable nature of incoming network packets caused the sporadic and hard to reproduce crashes.

Bug report at Apple was answered with the same explanation:

**Don't update the scene graph from multiple threads at the same time.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all this sentence

> The most safe version I think should be the following piece of code and it badly fails with the mentioned exception as well:

should **never** indicate a block of code where there is this symbol `!` :)

Now, there are a few wrong things in your code but basically you are **overremoving** your nodes.

### 1. deinit in ContainerNode is wrong

When you remove the parent of a node (and there are not other strong references to that node) it gets automatically (thanks ARC) deleted and its memory freed.
And, very important, this happen recursively to it children.

So your `ContainerNode` class becomes:

```
public class ContainerNode : SKNode {

    private let myNode : CustomNode

    override init() {
        self.myNode = CustomNode()
        super.init()
        self.addChild(self.myNode)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

//  deinit {
//      self.myNode.removeFromParent()
//      self.removeFromParent()
//  }
}
```

### 2. Same problem with CustomNode

Please update your code as well as described below.

```
public class CustomNode : SKNode {

    private let containerNode : SKNode
    private let child1 : SKNode

    override public init() {

        self.child1 = SKNode()

        self.containerNode = SKNode()

        super.init()

        self.containerNode.addChild(self.child1)

        self.addChild(self.containerNode)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

//  deinit {
//      
//      if self.child1.parent!.children.contains(self.child1) {
//          self.child1.removeFromParent()  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here !!
//      }
//      
//      self.containerNode.removeFromParent()
//      self.removeFromParent()
//  }

}
```

### 3. GameViewController

For some reason you removed this line from GameViewController

```
skView.showsNodeCount = true
```

If you add it to your code, let's say here

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true;
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

        skView.showsNodeCount = true // <<< add this
    }
}
```

You will be able to see on the bottom right corner of the screen the number of nodes added to the graph. You will see that after each tap 4 new nodes are added.
And after the 6th all nodes (but the scene) are removed and then 4 are immediately added again.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: W.r.t to 1) You are right :) I wanted to point out with the condition that parent is indeed still alive and valid object - but removeFromParent() still struggles for some reason. If parent would have been nil the condition would have failed instead of removeFromParent() and it would be clear that there's no parent anymore.

Comment: There are a few things in your code that are unnecessarily overcomplicated. And this `self.child1.parent!.children.contains(self.child1)` is the result. In SpriteKit (thanks to ARC) a node is automatically freed when there a no more references to it. You should rely on this mechanism instead of adding complex logic :-)

Comment: W.r.t 2) You said if there are no more references... however I have strong references to the child nodes namely the members in the node classes (myNode, containerNode, child1) So If deinit is called on the parent node it first removes the child from the node tree (via the child's deinit) and *after* returning from deinit on the parent the parent is gone (aka ARC collected).

Comment: You are right. The whole complexity was added when I tried to locate a issue in SKCRenderer which failed with bad access exceptions in a separate runloop.

Comment: Just update the code as I indicated in my answer, then add this method `deinit { debugPrint("CustomNode deallocated") }` to `CustomNode` and this `deinit { debugPrint("ContainerNode deallocated") }` to `ContainerNode`. You'll see on the console that your nodes now are correctly deallocated.

Comment: Yes - I can confirm that removing the deinit's makes the example not crash. But to be honest I still don't really get it. I will update my question accordingly. I must be still missing something.

Comment: I see your point and I understand what you want to know. How can the `IF` succeed and the `self.child1.removeFromParent()` fail? I confess I still haven't the answer. But I am looking for it :-)